# Let $\text{Rank}{(A - \lambda I)^k} = \text{Rank}{(B - \lambda I)^k}$. Why are $A$ and $B$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B \in M_n$ be two matrices such that $$\forall k=1,2,\dots,n,\ \forall \lambda\  \text{eigenvalue of $A$},\ \text{Rank}{(A - \lambda I)^k} = \text{Rank}{(B - \lambda I)^k}.$$ Why are $A$ and $B$ similar?

Comment: Notice that this requires an algebraically closed base field.

Comment: This is a classical consequence of the full classification of similar matrices (as explained for example in chapter 3 of Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*). To provide a meaningful answer, we have to know the things you already learned in linear algebra and module theory.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: both the hypothesis and the conclusion are invariant by field extension, so it cannot depend on the field being algebraically closed (actually, the result itself is probably the best way to see that matrices similar in an extension are already similar in the base field, so this remark is pretty circular).

Comment: Have you learned about Jordan canonical form yet?

Comment: @PseudoNeo: only if $\lambda$ is assumed to range over the algebraic closure.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh my goodness gracious, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite unclear as to what field we consider. As darij grinberg remarked, this is false on a general field.

**Example.** Let $\theta$, $\phi \in \left]0,\pi\right[$ be two distinct angles. Then the rotation matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and} \quad \begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix}$$
have no real eigenvalues. Still, these two matrices are not similar because their traces, $2 \cos \theta$ and $2 \cos \varphi$ are different.

A reasonable answer to your question is the following result.

**Proposition.** Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. We denote by $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ the set of eigenvalues of $A$ in $K$. Then, if
$$\forall \lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A),\ \forall 1 \leq k \leq n,\  \mathrm{rk}(A - \lambda I_n)^k = \mathrm{rk}(B - \lambda I_n)^k,$$
$A$ and $B$ are similar.

This proposition is a quite direct consequence of the following important result which explains the classification of matrices up to similarity in an algebraically closed field.

**Theorem (Jordan normal form).** Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $A \in M_n(K)$. Then, for every $\lambda \in \text{Spec}(A)$, there exists integers $m(\lambda)$ and $s_1(\lambda) \leq s_2(\lambda) \leq \cdots \leq s_{m(\lambda)}(\lambda)$ such that $A$ is similar to a block-diagonal matrix whose blocks are the $J_{s_i}(\lambda)$, for $\lambda \in \text{Spec}(A)$ and $i \leq m(\lambda)$, where
$$J_k(\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda \end{pmatrix}.$$
Besides, there is unicity of this decomposition, in the sense that the $m(\lambda)$ and the $s_i(\lambda)$ are uniquely defined.

(In particular, note that $n$ is the sum of the $s_i$). I will need this remark later, so I'll call it the *dimension formula*.

I certainly won't prove this theorem. It is probably proved in any good linear algebra book, but I don't really know this kind of books in English *["the gods have imposed upon my writing the yoke of a foreign language that was not sung at my cradle"]*. Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I* does it in its third chapter, but as a consequence of the classification of finitely generated modules over PIDs. It's very natural and enlightening, but it's not strictly necessary.

What I will do is deduce the proposition from the theorem.

*Notations.* I will use $m$ and the $s_i$ exactly as in the previous theorem. I will slightly extend it by considering that $m(\lambda) = 0$ if $\lambda$ isn't an eigenvalue of $A$. I will use $\mu$ and $\sigma_\iota$ for the corresponding attributes of $B$.

Because of the uniqueness part of the theorem, we have to prove that $\forall \lambda \in K, m(\lambda) = \mu(\lambda)$ and, for all $1 \leq i \leq m(\lambda)$, $s_i(\lambda) = \sigma_i(\lambda)$.

To prove the proposition, we have to prove that the different ranks you write are enough to determine the functions $m$ and $s_i$. To do that, remark that $\mathrm{rk}(J_s(\ell) - \lambda I_s)$ is $s$ if $\lambda \neq \ell$, but, if $k < s$,
$$\left(J_s(\ell) - \ell I_s\right)^k = J_s(0)^k$$
is a matrix having $s-k$ ones in the diagonal which is $k$ steps above the principal one. After that (for $k \geq s$), the matrix is $0$.

To sum up,
$$\left(J_s(\ell) - \ell I_s\right)^k = \begin{cases} s-k & \text{if } k \leq s \\ 0 & \text{if } k \geq s\end{cases} = (s-k)_+,$$
where the $+$ subscript means that, if the number in brackets is $< 0$, we replace it by $0$.

If you look at the decomposition, adding up the different blocks, you then get that $$\mathrm{rk}(A-\ell I_n)^k = \sum_{\lambda \neq \ell} m(\lambda) + \sum_{i=1}^{m(\ell)} (s_i(\ell) - k)_+.$$ 
In particular, note that, since all the $s_i(\ell)$ are $\leq n$, the quantities $\mathrm{rk}(A - \ell I_n)^k$ for $k > n$ (which are not included in the hypothesis of the proposition) are useless because they are simply $\sum_{\lambda \neq \ell} m(\lambda)=\mathrm{rk}(A - \ell I_n)^n.$

A small combinatorial reasoning then proves that your ranks determine everything: for $m$, this is direct:
$$\forall \lambda \in K,\ m(\lambda) = n - \mathrm{rk}(A - \lambda I_n)^n.$$
But it's a little more painful to write for the $s_i$. Basically, $\left(\mathrm{rk}(A - \lambda I_n)^k\right)_{k\geq 1}$ is a decreasing sequence and the "steps" are
$$\mathrm{rk}(A - \lambda I_n)^k - \mathrm{rk}(A - \lambda I_n)^{k+1} = \left| \left\{i \leq m(\lambda)\middle| s_i(\lambda) > k\right\}\right|.$$
And knowing how many $s_i(\lambda)$ are greater than $k$, for all $k$, is equivalent to knowing all of the $s_i(\lambda)$, because they are ordered. [Graphically, this is nothing but [the transposition of Young tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau), but I digress.]

At this stage, the proof is almost over. It would be over, but for the *caveat* that the hypothesis only gives the equalities between the ranks for $\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$. The previous discussion then gives the equalities for all the $\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and we still have to prove that $\forall \ell \in K \setminus \mathrm{Spec}(A), \mu(\ell) = 0$. This comes the fact that all the dimension has been "used up" to accomodate the blocks coming from $\textrm{Spec}(A)$.

More formally, it comes from the two dimension formulae for $A$ and $B$:
$$n = \sum_{\lambda\in K} \sum_{i=1}^{m(\lambda)} s_i(\lambda) = \sum_{\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} \sum_{i=1}^{m(\lambda)} s_i(\lambda)$$
$$\begin{align*}
n &= \sum_{\lambda\in K} \sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)} \sigma_i(\lambda) \\
&= \sum_{\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} \sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)} \sigma_i(\lambda) + \sum_{\lambda\not\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)} \sigma_i(\lambda)\\
&= \sum_{\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} \sum_{i=1}^{m(\lambda)} s_i(\lambda) + \sum_{\lambda\not\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)} \sigma_i(\lambda)\\
&= n + \sum_{\lambda\not\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)} \sigma_i(\lambda),\end{align*}$$
which gives $\sum_{\lambda\not\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)}\sum_{i=1}^{\mu(\lambda)}\sigma_i(\lambda) = 0$ so $\forall\lambda\not\in\mathrm{Spec}(A), \mu(\lambda) = 0$.

At last, we're done.