# suppose $tr(A^k) = tr(B^k)$ for all $k$=$1,2,....$. why $A$ and $B$ are same characteristic polynomial? .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_n}$ and suppose $tr(A^k) = tr(B^k)$ for all $k$=$1,2,...$ . Why do $A$ and $B$ possess the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597743/diagonalizable-matrices-a-and-b-with-mathrmtrak-mathrmtrbk-have-th and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923523/showing-that-m-and-n-will-have-same-eigenvalues

Comment: I must say I really dislike this "$M_n$" notation, which doesn't mention the field. (I have already seen it in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268459, whose style is somewhat comparable to the one at hand).

Comment: This is duplicate with all the questions linked to in comments above, of which curiously **every single one forgets to mention the necessary condition on the characteristic**. ([The result is not true](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/597991) in characteristic$~p$ with $0<p\leq n$). This is really sad. Closing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix).

To be more specific, Newton's identities show that the result you quote is true on a field of characteristic $0$. It is false on a positive characteristic field, though: for example, on $\mathbb F_2$, you have $\mathrm{tr}(I_2) = \mathrm{tr}(0) = 0$, but these two $2\times 2$ matrices don't have the same determinant.